# Google charts: Data from .json file

Tags: jquery, html, json, google-visualization

I am trying to draw a line graph using google charts using values from a .json file. I have tried but haven't been successful.

This is the my .json file

```
[
   {
      "Year":2005,
      "Sales":25000,
   },
   {
      "Year":2006,
      "Sales":25085,
   },
   {
      "Year":2007,
      "Sales":186230,
   },
   {
      "Year":2008,
      "Sales":35036,
   },
   {
      "Year":2009,
      "Sales":15900,
   },
   {
      "Year":2010,
      "Sales":35700,
   }
]
```

Code

```
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function loadData(fileName) { 
        // getting json from a remote file
        // by returning the jqXHR object we can use the .done() function on it
        // so the callback gets executed as soon as the request returns successfully
        return $.getJSON( fileName + ".json");
    }

    function drawChart() {
            var myFile = "Data";

        var obj= loadData(myFile);
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(obj);

        var options = {
            title: 'Chart Demo'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(
                    document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
     }
```

Error

```
Error: Not an array
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js
Line 2
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Could you put a `console.log(data);` after the line `var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(obj);` and see what you are getting...

Comment: @Will.i.am Still getting same error in the console

Comment: Note that you declare a variable called `dataTable` that is never used.

Comment: ya it was for another need. I removed it.

Comment: What you are getting in the console for `console.log(data);`? Paste here...

Comment: Error: Not an array
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js
Line 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to get json data from the file.

```
var data = $.ajax({
                 url: "Data",
                 dataType: "json",
                 async: false,
                 }).responseText;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// by returning the jqXHR object we can use the .done() function on it
// so the callback gets executed as soon as the request returns successfully
```

You don't use the `.done()`, so when you pass `obj` you are passing an `jqXHR` object that most likely has not even fetched the data.

---

This should work:

```
function drawChart() {
    var myFile = "Data";

    //Use getJSON and process the file contents in the callback function
    $.getJSON(myFile + '.json', function(obj) {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(obj);

        var options = {
            title: 'Chart Demo'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    });
}
```

Comment: Since I haven't worked with google visualization I cannot help you with that. I can only point out faulty jQuery/javascript.